# Material Chips - Can't find resource ID (Color/Icon)

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, material-design

Relevant code:

```
fun updateCategories(categories: List<Category>) {
    categories.forEach {
        var chipText = "${it.title.capitalize()} (${it.amount})"
        val chip = Chip(context)
        chip.text = chipText
        chip.isCheckable = true
        chip.chipBackgroundColor = null
        when(it.title.toLowerCase()){ 
            "utilities" -> {
                chip.setChipIconTintResource(Color.parseColor("#115FFF"))
                chip.setChipStrokeColorResource(Color.parseColor("#115FFF"))                    
           chip.setChipDrawable(ChipDrawable.createFromResource(this.context, R.drawable.ic_utilities))
            }

        chips_group.addView(chip)
    }
}
```

So for this code, I had 2 errors,
`Expected a color resource id (R.color.) but received an RGB integer` for the colors
and `Expected resource of type xml` for the drawables

I could fix this error by adding a `@SuppressLint("ResourceType")`, but this resulted in runtime errors when reaching this code about not finding the resource either the color id or the drawable

The error if i comment colors and keep drawables is 
`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't load chip resource ID #0x7f070078`

the error for the colors is
`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff115fff`

any help is appreciated.

What im attempting to do is to add a chip with an icon i specified and color that I picked, this is the result I hope to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the errors you're facing is **Expected a color resource id (R.color.)**

That is because instead of passing `R.color.tint_resource` to `setChipIconTintResource` and `setChipStrokeColorResource` you are passing `Color.parseColor(colorString)`

Move the hex codes to `colors.xml` and use them.

Second thing, the reason you are getting resource not found exception is that `createFromResource` takes an xml resource and your passing a drawable resource. So, Create a xml resource file in the res/xml folder.

After making the changes, your code will look something like below.

```
chip.setChipIconTintResource(R.color.chip_icon_tint)
chip.setChipStrokeColorResource(R.color.chip_stroke_color)
chip.setChipDrawable(
    ChipDrawable.createFromResource(this, R.xml.chip_resource)
)
```

Finally, Adding `@SuppressLint` just suppress the warning escalating the chances of a run time crash compared to solving the issue.

**Set Chip Icon:**

```
chip.chipIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_utilities)
```

**Set Stroke Width:**

```
chip.chipStrokeWidth = 6f
```

Comment: Create an xml resource file in res/xml containing what? how do i use the svg I want to use in it? create new vector asset as i've been doing?

Comment: I just moved the old asset file i had in drawable to res/xml and used it, still crashing on code being reached, this is how it's looking right now https://i.imgur.com/sSuqBlD.png

Comment: If all you want is to set the vector asset to the chip, simply do so using `chipIcon` (for usage check the updated answer).

Comment: Thank you, now the icon appears properly, but im still getting an error for the colors and no color appearing, `Invalid ID 0x00000000`

Comment: What i did is add the color to my res/values/colors.xml  file as `<color name="utilitiesColor">#115FFF</color>` and set it in code as `chip.setChipStrokeColorResource(R.color.utilitiesColor)
 chip.setChipIconTintResource(R.color.utilitiesColor)`

Comment: Invalid ID at what line?

Comment: `E/ark.{mypackagename}: Invalid ID 0x00000000` is all it says, says it twice.

Comment: Its ok to ignore it but looking at the screenshot provided, you can see the color was not applied. @Srikar Reddy

Comment: Did you convert the SVG file to vector asset? I can't see an icon left of utilities?

Comment: The icon is there, it's just not visible due to it being white as the same as the background, now i'm trying to stroke it into a circle as in the design but apparently, that's not possible programatically? I've opened a question for that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55333780/setting-material-chip-icon-stroke-background-color

Comment: Are you sure `chip.setChipIconTintResource(R.color.utilitiesColor)` doesn't work? It works for me and I can see the tint added to the icon.

Comment: What is the value of the color `chip_icon_tint`?

Comment: It works now my friend, I just had to set the icon before setting the tint. It was overwriting it as I was setting the icon in the end. many thanks