# Setting Material chip Icon stroke/background color

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

so I'm trying to generate a button that looks like this [image]

so far what I've achieved looks like this
[image: M]

This is the code I'm using

```
                chip.setChipStrokeColorResource(R.color.utilitiesColor)
                chip.chipStrokeWidth = 2.0f
                chip.setChipIconTintResource(R.color.utilitiesColor)  //T
                chip.setCloseIconTintResource(R.color.utilitiesColor) //T
                chip.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#115fff"))
                chip.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
                chip.chipIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, R.drawable.ic_utilities)
```

The 2 lines i've commented with T are the ones I tried adding to achieve this icon background color but they don't seem to change anything, you may not see the icon in the picture but it's there its just white on white so you can't see without the stroke.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to design your icon accordingly with colors you want.

Comment: Gotcha, just thought an icon background thing would exist. thanks

Comment: @KaranMer Pardon, but I was googling and it seems setChipIconTintResource should be doing what I desire, are you sure that's not the case?

Comment: You are right I checked in xml and it works. Can you change your code to set chipicon first and then set the tint.

Comment: Yeah now it's functioning atleast but it seems what it does is paint the vector I have, not surround it as I want it to, this is the result achieved http://prntscr.com/n2j9ss , Any other programatic ideas or ideas about creating/changing the vector drawables I have or do I have to tackle this design-wise?

Comment: you can create reverse vector of this this is what you exactly want.

Comment: How can I go about that?

Comment: I am no expert in creating vectors but if you search about create reverse vector you will find lot of results about how to do it using photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this formate

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Utilites (200)"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
         />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image" />
```

**round.xml**

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="10dp" />

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<stroke
    android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:width="2dp">

</stroke>
```